# Converting an Image type PDF to an OCR enabled PDF

Tags: image, pdf, text, ocr

I'm not sure if my title is overly descriptive of what I'm trying to do so I will try and elabarate.

I've been asked to develop a small application where someone can upload a PDF to the website. The website is coded in ASP classic but I don't mind going down the route of .net.

Once uploaded the code needs to check if the PDF is text based if it is not it needs to then convert the document over to the text type PDF.

Does anyone have an idea of a component that can do this image PDF to text PDF conversion? So far i've looked into:

- http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/
- http://www.websupergoo.com/abcocr-1.htm

I didn't overly understand what the ghost thing was doing and the websupergoo solution appeared to be converting images into text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford a commercial option, you could use [Amyuni PDF Creator .Net](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator) with asp.net, or [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex) if you want to stay on asp-classic. Take a look on the [OCR module](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/ocrmodule) for PDF-Image to PDF-Text processing.

*Usual disclaimer applies*

Comment: Great I will look into your suggestions, sorry for the late reply, I was not emailed the response notification so didn't realise there had been replies!

Comment: I've not got the suggested working yet (got a ticket open with their support) however it looks like when working it will be the perfect solution!

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use one of several websites that let you upload an image and send you back an OCR'ed data. Try [www.ocrsdk.com](http://www.ocrsdk.com), it is a cloud based OCR SDK recently launched by ABBYY. It's now in closed beta so it's completely free to use.